# Consuming WCF service in VB application

Tags: vb.net, wcf

Correct me If I am doing wrong,

I have just started to check WCF services so have created a sample WCF service application with two methods IService

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}
```

And wanted to consume this service in VB application so added my service using 
Servicereference>>Advanced>>AddWebreference

after that trying to call the method in the service on a simple button click in VB form

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As    
   System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim client As New localhost.Service1
    client.GetData(10, True)
End Sub
```

But when am trying to execute the button click am getting the TimeOut Exception..
Can some one assist me on what am I doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just the Service Reference to the WCF service, Web Reference is for ASMX.

Also, if you have Visual Studio 2010, under Tools, you will see a built-in 'WCF Test Client' to verify your service.

Finally, using a Service Reference is convenient, but it generates a lot of unnecessary files (especially if you use source control), so suggest using a single file (.vb or .cs) in the form of a proxy class. This is auto-generated via svcutil.exe (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx) for more details).

Comment: Thanks Channs,It worked!!! will see working with svcutil.exe any more references on that will help me a lot.

Comment: @DarkRider - Related references can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734691.aspx. Start using it to get a better idea.